# Resizing an icon to fit an <input> field

Tags: html, css, autoresize

I have an input field which has an icon inside of it, I did this by using css `background`

```
background: white url("user.png") right no-repeat;
```

the image is a bit big so I was wondering how do I resize the image to fit inside the `<input>` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`background-size: cover` or `background-size: 100% 100%`

It is a property of CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier just to resize the image in PS or another image editor, so that it's the right size?

Comment: The image is used in another area that requires it to be that size. I figured resizing it down would be a better option than to have the browser download double the files, this might seem small but it adds up if there are more resources like this.

Comment: No worries, I didn't realise you were using the image more than once at different sizes.

Comment: yeah sorry I should have mentioned that haha xD

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Assuming this is something u want to achieve, you can size the background-image.
Use percentages to size it relative to height and width of the textfield

```
     .input-fields {
     background: white url(images/invalid.png) no-repeat;
     background-position: 97%;
     background-size: 8% 85%;
     border-color: var(--red);
     }
```

This will make it small enough to fit inside the textfield.
background-position: 97% (to leave some space at the end)